# adding function result to list while checking it

Tags: c#

As I do that often enough i was wondering if there is a neat way to skip using a variable. I have a function that returns a List of unknown length. I want to add the result to another list and also know if i got returned an empty list. I could save the function result in a variable and see if its empty and otherwise add it to the list. I just was thinking if this could be done more elegantly.
I also could do:

```
myList.AddRange(getFiles(path));
if(getFiles(path).Count == 0)
{
doSomething();
}
```

getFiles being an example function that returns a list of files at a path

That way however I have to call the function twice.

This is more of a programming style question as I am quite unexperienced. Should one make a "tmp" variable everytime this happens?

Comment: Have you looked into a `List<dynamic>` and `ExpandoObject`s ?

Comment: Why don't you want to store it in a variable? Regardless your example is bad practice.. the saying goes something like 'Query once, use many times' ie. run your method only once and if you need what it returns store it in a local variable and use that

Comment: If you build a large system and end up maintaining it, you will be kicking yourself for "_skip[ing] using a variable_".  If someone else ends up maintaining it, they will be quietly cursing you forever.  Variables have names that are great for documenting what's going on (much better than comments).  They also make debugging _way_ easier.  At worse, they add 4 or 8 bytes to the stack frame (i.e., nearly nothing), but, if they are really skippable, then the JIT will eliminate them in your production code, so they cost nothing (other than some typing).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make this extension method:

```
public static int AddRangeEx<T>(this List<T> target, IEnumerable<T> items)
{
    int result = items.Count();
    if( result > 0 ) target.AddRange(items);
    return result;
}
```

And then you'll be able to write code like this:

```
if(myList.AddRangeEx(getfiles(path)) > 0)
{
    doSomething();
}
```

Alternatively, if you're concerned about side effects of the extra `Count()` call (even just performance side effects, but there are lots of ways to get an IEnumerable that can only run one time), you could build the extension method this way:

```
public static int AddRangeEx<T>(this List<T> target, IEnumerable<T> items)
{
    int result = 0;
    foreach (T item in items)
    {
        target.Add(item);
        result++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Which isn't really any different than what `AddRange()` and `Count()` were already doing.

As a bonus, you can overload the extension method for improved performance on types that already know the count:

```
public static int AddRangeEx<T>(this List<T> target, T[] items)
{
    if (items.Length > 0)
        target.AddRange(items);
    return items.Length;
}
```

It kind of makes me sad the built-in `AddRange()` method doesn't already do this for us.

Answer (score 2):

The first choice is to just store a local variable

```
var files = getFiles(path);
myList.AddRange(files);
if(files.Count == 0)
{
    doSomething();
}
```

The second choice would be this

```
var count = myList.Count
myList.AddRange(getFiles(path));
if(myList.Count > count)
{
    doSomething();
}
```

Comment: Seems to me this should be an `if/`else` block and the `AddRange()` call should only be executed if Count != 0. This would more clearly communicate the behavior, and calling AddRange with an empty collection does have a small amount of overhead.